# Parse iOS version 1.4.2

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have noticed that when use parse version 1.4.2 in one of my iOS apps it doesn't store information like "parseVersion", "timeZone" in "Installation" Class. Is this a bug ? or is it normal ?

Because of this reason I have shift back to 1.4.1. Because I really need "timeZone" information.

If its not a bug then how can I send a push notifications to users in particular timeZone ?

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its was bug. But seems like a rare one.

"Fixed rare problem with saving automatic data on PFInstallation."

[iOS / OS X Changelog - v1.5.0](https://parse.com/docs/downloads/)

Now its all good and we have v1.5.0. :)

Answer (score 0):

At my app (iOS 7 & 8 / Parse SKD 1.4.2) there is no issue by saving informations like "timeZone" or "parseVersion" automatically on the app launch...

But here is a little workaround for you - you can save the timeZone manually:

```
NSTimeZone *defaultTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setObject:defaultTimeZone forKey:@"defaultTimeZone"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Thanks. But several times I have removed and put back the the SDK 1.4.2 but still no luck. Your workaround is fine but I just need to understand the issue here. I'm about to release the app and I'm bit worry because if that is a bug in SDK.

Comment: I have been using Parse for long time but this is the first time I got this issue.

Comment: Mmm that's really confused! I also use parse since several years and never got any problems with this... Did you test your app on a real device?

Comment: Yes I did. Tested with iOS 6,7,8 all same but no issues with 1.4.1.

Comment: Okay that's weird! I think the best solution for you would be using 1.4.1 - maybe there is really a bug in 1.4.2 and you better waiting for an update..

Answer (score 0):

I have the seme problem too!
I've attached the screen shot of some installation from an iPad 2 and an iPhone 5.
[image: Parse Console screenshot]
It seems that all the data apart the deviceToken are not even saved in the local `PFInstallation`, because if I try to print the `timeZone` it return `nil`.
Very weird, and prior to the 1.4.2 all works fine, I think that I will go back to the old version for now waiting for an update.